# Mule ESB reinstall

Tags: installation, windows-server-2008, service, reinstall

I am trying to reinstall [Mule ESB](http://www.mulesoft.org/) on my Windows Server machine and noticed something odd:

When I had previously installed it, the service used to be listed under the Administrative Tools ->  Services automatically. Then I tried to uninstall Mule because I thought something was went really wrong. I also had to run `sc delete mule` to get rid of all traces of it.  According to this [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742045%28WS.10%29.aspx), sc deletes a service subkey from the registry.  Now when I try to install Mule, it is no longer listed as a service.

Have I permanently deleted Mule ESB forever from this list? How can I get it back onto the services list? Or is there an alternative way to check to see that it is running or to start and stop the service?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: mule being [this](http://www.mulesoft.org/)? in case the solution is generic as opposed to specific to mule, it might be useful to link the software in question. There's also M.U.L.E or [mule](http://www.xemacs.org/Releases/Public-21.2/projects/mule-nt.html) for xemacs and...

Comment: Ah, sorry, it is Mule ESB.

Answer (score 0):

Having deleted the keys from the registry you could try 3 paths to fix this issue :

1. Asuming that you have deleted only one key and there are still information in the registry which remained after the first Mule install I would recommend you would use something like CCLeaner to clean the registry and retry to install again
2. Install Mule on a virtual machine with the same OS and requierements that Mule has then copy the registry keys from on to another
3. Revert with System restore to a previous time when you haven't had Mule installed on that server , then install it as usual
   4.Manually recreate the keys from the registry(this is quite imposible )

Hope this helps ,
Alex H

Comment: If the key from the registry was added during the mule installation, would you happen to know why it isn't being added again during another installation after the keys are deleted?  Thanks!

Comment: I supose it is because you manually deleted only one of the keys from registry and probably there are still entries which can't be overwriten by Mule when you try to reinstall it